# org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger vs org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger

Tags: java, log4j2

Can anyone explain the difference between the `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger` and `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`?

Sorry if this is a broad question but most documentation just talks about Logger and I don't know why there are 2 of them. Is there an easy way to convert between them? To put it another way can you explain what core signifies?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc? Second one in an implementation and second one is only an interface as part of the api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It got answered in the comments.  core.Logger is an implementation of Logger which is an interface.  So if I understand this correctly I should be able to cast instances of Logger into core.Logger
Thank you.